Must an ideal of a ring be a subring?
In my text by Hillman & Alexander an ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ is defined as a subring with the properties that for every $a\in I$ and every $r\in R$, the products $ar$ and $ra$ are in $I$. But if this is the case then if $R$ is a ring with identity then every ideal is $R$ itself. This doesn't seem to be right.

Do Hillman & Alexander define a ring to be a structure which has a multiplicative identity? If they do not require this, then an ideal is a subring of any ring (whether or not that ring happens to possess a multiplicative identity).

You should add the definition of ring and subring that the book uses. There is not really one single universal definition of ring.

I have closed this as a duplicate. If the linked answers don't answer your question, please indicate why. But please use the search feature next time. Every question concerning basic definitions has been discussed a couple of times here.
